# How to hide a TCheckListBox Item?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a quite long list of (string) values in a TCheckListBox.

I want to allow the user to do some simple filtering of this list by checking some external CheckBoxes, indicating the filters.

In order to save some coding, I'm looking for a solution that simply hides filtered items in the TCheckListBox.

Question is, is this even possible?

I have found that there are ways to set individual items 'state' and enabled properties, but can't find a 'visible' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "hide" list box items.  You must physically remove them from the list.  So during your filtering process, you will have to re-populate the list box to display only the relevant items that match the current filter.

Otherwise, switch to something like a [Virtual TreeView](http://www.jam-software.com/virtual-treeview/) instead (despite its name, it can also be used to simulate lists and grids as well as trees).  Its nodes can be hidden without actually removing them.